# Exploiting fopen when input has extension appended

Tags: php, security, exploit

For science.

Say I have the following code:

```
<?php
$filename = $_GET['filename'] . '.csv';
$handle = @fopen($filename);
```

We know that the null byte exploit is long gone, but is it possible to get around the above appending of .csv, in order to read a file with another extension? Very creative souls exist.

Reading remote files works, filename=http://example.com/some.csv (.csv is appended automatically).

Comment: Exploit in what manner? And what do you do with that file / handle?

Comment: I wonder, would `example.pdf?ommit.csv` work?..

Comment: Ah, I should've added that. The handler reading the file as a CSV, but this process might spit out information even if a file is not an actual CSV (comma or semicolon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you query for `http://example.com/some.pdf?csv`, `fopen` will try to gather the pdf file...

Rather use regex to validate `$_GET` (you should **always** validate your input):

`/(\.csv)$/g` will help you validate whether the extension is `.csv`